# Docker - Issues sharing volume host:container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Im trying to use **docker-compose for running several services (redis, mongo and express app)**. I want to have my host "connected" to the container, so modifying files will modify files too in the container.

The **express app has its Dockerfile** that run `npm install`.

When I try `docker-compose up`, Im getting the following error:

```
web_1    | [nodemon] 1.9.2
web_1    | [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
web_1    | [nodemon] watching: *.*
web_1    | [nodemon] starting `node server/app.js`
web_1    | module.js:328
web_1    |     throw err;
web_1    |     ^
web_1    | 
web_1    | Error: Cannot find module 'express'
web_1    |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:326:15)
web_1    |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:277:25)
web_1    |     at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
web_1    |     at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
web_1    |     at Object.<anonymous> (/blog/server/app.js:5:15)
web_1    |     at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
web_1    |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
web_1    |     at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
web_1    |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
web_1    |     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
web_1    | [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

It complains that **it cannot find express module**.

**To check that the build process installed properly the dependencies specified in the package.json**, Im running the container with /bin/bash entrypoint:

```
docker run -it --rm --entrypoint /bin/bash image_name
```

**Inside the container, `node_modules` folder exists**. I can also run `nodemon server/app` and express app runs properly (missing the connection from the other services of course).

Here it is the `Dockerfile´ for the express app:

```
FROM node:argon
MAINTAINER xxxxxxxx

# Install globally nodemon
RUN npm install nodemon -g

# Make folder that contains blog
RUN mkdir -p blog

# Set up working directory (from now on we are located inside /blog)
WORKDIR /blog

# Add package
ADD ./package.json /blog

# Install dependencies defined in packaje.json
RUN npm install

# Copy data
ADD ./ /blog
```

And here the `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"

  cache:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"

  web:
    environment: 
      NODE_ENV: 'development'
    build: .
    command: nodemon server/app.js
    volumes:
      - ./:/blog
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - cache
      - db
```

**Could it be something related to VOLUMES?**.

In my local environment I dont have node_modules folder. Is the `volumes` tag that I defined in the docker-compose.yml hiding the `node_modules folder` built with `docker-compose built`?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Dockerfile you are doing the following

```
ADD ./ /blog
```

This is taking your local directory and adding to the image at /blog, and oyu are then installing your npm packages, I assume into the same /blog directory.

Then in your docker-compose file you say the following:

```
  volumes:
  - ./:/blog
```

This is taking the /blog directory in your image, throwing it away and replacing it with your local directory. Since you didn't run npm install on your local machine, you wouldn't have the node_modules directory there, and so when you run the container, it won't have express, and thus your error.

To solve this, you should store your npm packages somewhere other than under /blog, maybe globally, and then you won't have to worry about this issue.

To do that, you would change your dockerfile from

```
RUN npm install
```

to

```
RUN npm install -g
```

That will install your npm modules globally (outside of /blog) and then when you run the container, it should just work.